# Create an image of a clean installation

Tags: windows-7, backup, disk-image

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Creating image of Windows installation](https://superuser.com/questions/315242/creating-image-of-windows-installation)
>   [Computer refresh - Efficiently cloning 60 indentical computers](https://superuser.com/questions/277135/computer-refresh-efficiently-cloning-60-indentical-computers)

I occasionally format my computer because it gets quite full with programs and documents I don't really need. So once in a while I format it so it's faster and I lose all the junk.

I would like to create an image of my clean installation and was wondering what are good opensource options? I have found a few possibilities:

- ImageX
- Symantec Ghost
- DriveImage XML
- Acronis True Image

I also have one or two other computers that I occasionally format, is it possible to use the same image on those computers? Would there be any problems with drivers or license keys? Ifso, how could I solve these?

Thank you for your time and help!

Tom

Comment: Some drivers depend on Motherboard so I think if your motherboards are smae then you will not face any problem.

Comment: Motherboards will probably be different. Dell XPS M1530 Laptop and HP desktop.

Comment: Then according to me you will face the problem with drivers. I didn't use these settings ever so can't say about too much. But one of mine friend was telling me that this doesn't work very well some problems occur.

Comment: Okay, so images are only used for the same computers or computers with the same hardware? Is there a way to create some sort of image that's suitable for all computers, or is this still wishful thinking?

Comment: Hmmmm let me find it and I will tell you if there is way or not to do this.

Comment: Its interesting, I think he asked it on stackoverflow and now he asked it here.

Comment: Yes indeed, problem was I couldn't post on it anymore.

Comment: You are looking for a product with "Bare Metal Restore" if you want to move an image to a new computer. Acronis has that if you buy the "Acronis® True Image™ Home 2011 Plus Pack". You would need to change the licence keys for each computer.

Comment: thank you :) Is Acronis a good piece of software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No if the hardware is the same then it will work otherwise its not worthy to install the same image on other computer. But you can check by install it. In some cases drivers compatible with other hardware if not just go to control panel and uninstall them and re-install the original drivers of the Devices.

Comment: Okay, but you were looking to see if there is a way?

Comment: After finding some information I'm giving you this suggestion.

Comment: You are welcome we are here to help each-other

Comment: Not really true. Acronis True Image Home can be purchased with Bare Metal Restore. This allows for using an image on a new computer. You load the new drivers asas part of the process of coping the image to the new computer.

Comment: Then what's the real difference between installing a fresh copy of windows and in this. Just haven't to install software.

Comment: Then in the same way i suggested him in my answer to install the image on other computer and just uninstall the incompatible drivers and install the original drivers of the system. I think the procedure is same.